# javascript format issues with ()

Tags: javascript

i got a little code but it doesnt work. i think i have an error with the ( ) cause there are too many x)

code:

```
if (structure == null) {
    console.log('so far so good: ');
    if (_.sum(Game.getObjectById(57 f5db55fc5a39220c785df5).store) < Game.getObjectById(57 f5db55fc5a39220c785df5).storeCapacity) {
        if (creep.transfer(Game.getObjectById(57 f5db55fc5a39220c785df5), RESOURCE_ENERGY, creep.energy) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
            // move towards it
            creep.moveTo(Game.getObjectById(57 f5db55fc5a39220c785df5));
        }
    }

}
```

anyone can understand what went wrong here? :p

Comment: Some error in console?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: error stays. tried that already :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your IDs (example: 57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5 -> '57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5').

Since you're not enclosing them with quotes, it's regarded as an non-existent variable by the interpreter. And if you got some illegal characters there, it will fail even before trying to resolve the variable.

Comment: Okay, now atleast i got a different Error in the console: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Trying to compare if the amount of energy in the storage object is less than the maximum capacity. ( object = http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/208436805-StructureStorage)

Comment: there was just 1 line with a '<' in it :p Anyway, i read the wiki page again about the container unit i try to adress and i found a simpler way if i just go by room.storage... and since i can have only 1 of those storages i dont need to check it by id x)

Answer (score 1):

`57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5` can't be a variable name, nor can it be an integer as it contains characters - so it's a string. In javascript, you need to enclose strings with `"` or `'`

```
if (structure == null) {
    console.log('so far so good: '); 
    if (_.sum(Game.getObjectById("57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5").store) < Game.getObjectById("57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5").storeCapacity){
        if (creep.transfer(Game.getObjectById("57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5"), RESOURCE_ENERGY, creep.energy) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
            // move towards it
            creep.moveTo(Game.getObjectById("57f5db55fc5a39220c785df5"));
        }                    
    }

}
```